# React, Redux , Typescript and Sass bundled using Webpack and Vite

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, redux, sass

So I created two projects using **React + Redux + SASS + Typescript** with
**Vite and Webpack**.

I was amazed using **Vite** as the configuration part was pre handled as compared to **Webpack**. But again my project is big so I'd prefer **Webpack** over **Vite**.

`LINK FOR VITE PROJECT` : https://codesandbox.io/p/github/MrIndra/ReactRedux/csb-n4u7e3/draft/reverent-bohr?file=%2Fdist%2Findex.html&selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A8%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A6%2C%22startColumn%22%3A8%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A6%7D%5D

`LINK FOR WEBPACK PROJECT:` https://codesandbox.io/p/github/MrIndra/react-sass-typescript-webpack/draft/affectionate-cookies?import=true&file=%2Fbuild%2Fmain.css&selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A36%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A4%2C%22startColumn%22%3A36%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A4%7D%5D
,

***Note*** : All the images `test: /\.(?:ico|gif|png|jpg|jpeg)$/i,` generated after build will be in their same parent folders as before build.

**Current Problem**

I have `index.module.scss` in the root directory which contains all the root level variables. Now again in every components, I have placed folder/component `folder.module.scss` files. Now `npm run build` is generating weird kind of css file.[image below]

[image]

**The snapshot for the configuration of SCSS `test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,` is**

[image]
.

**The `folder.module.scss` looks something like this**

[image]

And the output where the buttons is not styled with the scss provided.
[image]

Comment: Update your sass rule as follows,
ex: { test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i, use: [ MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, { loader: "css-loader", options: { modules: false } }, "sass-loader"]
It should fix your problem, refer to https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/#modules for an explanation

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are trying to bundle all css/scss into one single css file. If so try following.

// install sass-loader and sass implementation of your choice
npm i sass-loader css-loader sass --save-dev

//install this plugin to extract CSS/Sass into separate or single file

npm i --save-dev mini-css-extract-plugin

and add following to your webpack config,

```
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = {
  plugins: [new MiniCssExtractPlugin()],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Comment: I've revamped my project and used webpack. However I am unbale to style my buttons under ```Cake``` component and moreover the build index.css contains weird classnames. Your help is highly appreciated.